# go micro blob.db error when executing micro run . in Windows 10

Tags: go, microservices, go-micro

I wrote a basic [micro](https://github.com/micro/micro) service. Both `micro new` and `make proto` work fine. All dependencies installed. `micro server` also running, BUT, when I do `cd myservice` and then `micro run .` ( I have local env by the way) this errors shows:

`Rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error writing source to blob store: open C:\Windows\micro\store\blob.db:  El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada(System can not find the specified route)`.

I have the micro binaries in my go `installfolder/bin` this way

```
C:\Program Files\Go\bin
λ ls
bin 
go.exe  
gofmt.exe
include
micro.exe
```

I dont know what I am missing but `go mod tidy` and `go mod vendor` execute well. Anyway, I have the feeling that running micro in windows is a headache.

Comment: Without see any sample code, this will be hard to debug.  It seems that the default blob store is not / has not been created.

Comment: @GariSingh that s the problem. Its just the generated code of micro with micro new service_name. 
I did not see any reference to such a blob store, i just downloaded the micro binaries and unzip them in my golang install-dir. Can you give me some hint about the blob store??? Dont know what is that